# MAX5825 full scale on 8 bits

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c, digital-analog-converter, pigpio

I am using a MAX5825 as an external DAC for RPi. 
According to the datasheet, the resolution of this component is [12 bits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/th8fv.png). 
As I read, I'm supposed to write the value I want to set in the CODEn (0x8n) register, n being the DAC channel I want to set, and then write anything in the LOADn (0x9n) register, or use the CODEn_LOADn (0xBn) register to do it in one step. [See here the datasheet extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FQP7.png). 
I'm using pigpio daemon library to interface I²C communication

```
void AnalogOutput::updateValue(int value) { 
    i2c_write_word_data(my_pi_device, my_handler, 0xB0, value << 4);
}
```

This is supposed to set my CODE0 register to the *value* parameter.
However, I had a strange behavior so I tried to read the data from CODEn (0x80) register to watch if my set attempt was correct.

```
i2c_read_word_data(my_pi_device, my_handler, 0x80);
```

I'm not sure I can read a value from a command register tho, but when my value exceed 0xFF, the return I get from I²C reading looks like *value & 0xFF*. (i.e. when I set the register to 0xFF I read 0xFF in the register, when I set the register to 0x100 I read 0x00)
Also, the output voltage of my DAC0 channel is at its maximum scale when CODEn register is set to 0xFF. I used 4.0V internal reference and when I set *value* to 0xFF, the output voltage is 4.0V-ish. 
I don't understand why is 0xFF the maximum scale on a 12-bits resolution DAC ? Am I missing a way to configure the resolution or anything like that ? 
What I've tried so far :

- Remove the << 4 shifting on the set value : no change on the behavior
- Invert the LSByte and MSByte written to the CODEn register (I've seen
  on pigpiod API SMBus standard was supposed to send LSByte then MSByte
  in a word writing procedure) : the reading of CODEn register was
  jumping over 0x0FFF value. MAX5825 is supposed to be compatible with
  SMBus standard tho.
- Use *i2c_write_block_data* instead of
  *i2c_write_word_data* function of pigpiod lib : no change on the
  behavior.

Thanks for your time ! 
 
References : 
MAX5825 datasheet : https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX5823-MAX5825.pdf 
pigpio API : https://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pdif2.html

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it fixed using i2cget & i2cset, my supposition about LSByte & MSByte was right. 
CODEn registers are filled with 12 MSB. That means a set value of 0x0ABC needs to be stored in CODEn register by : 0xABC0. pigpio following SMBus standard send I²C word message with LSByte first and then MSByte, so if I send 0x0ABC message through I²C it will actually send 0xBC0A. When I tried to invert LSByte and MSByte, I was sending through I²C the message 0xBC0A so what was stored inside MAX5825 was 0x0AB. 
One functionnal workaround would be :

```
void AnalogOutput::updateValue(int value) {
    int codeRegisterData = (value >> 4) + ((value & 0xF)<<12);
    i2c_write_word_data(my_pi_device, my_handler, 0xB0, codeRegisterData);
}
```

If *value* = 0x0ABC, *codeRegisterData* would be = 0xC0AB so pigpio will write over the I²C bus into the CODEn register the message 0xABC0.